# Scrapy Python. How do I get the "item_scraped_count" in the terminal?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to python programming and webscraping. My intended code is to scrape the title, price and url of the book in the website. However, I was not able to get the wanted message in my terminal, which is "item_scraped_count" which ususally have been included in the tutorial terminal, in contrast of mine.

This is my code block

```
import scrapy


class BookspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bookspider"
    allowed_domains = ["books.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://books.toscrape.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.css('article.product_prod')

        for book in books:
            yield{
                'title' : book.css("h3 a::text").get(),
                'price' : book.css(".product_price .product_color::text").get(),
                'url' : book.css("h3 a").attrib['href']
            }

        next_page = response.css("li.next a::attr(href)").get()

        if next_page is not None:
            if 'catalogue/' in next_page:
                next_page_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/' + next_page
            else:
                next_page_url = 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/' + next_page
            yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

This is the result in the terminal:

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 15159,
 'downloader/request_count': 51,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 51,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2556339,
 'downloader/response_count': 51,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 50,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 20.302593,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 27, 12, 54, 23, 623889, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 54,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 49,
 'response_received_count': 51,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 50,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 50,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 50,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 50,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 27, 12, 54, 3, 321296, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
2023-12-27 19:54:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I would like to thank you in advance for helping me out with this problem

I tried to get the "item_scraped_count" in my terminal but it doesn't shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `item_scraped_count` stat because there were no items scraped.

There were no items scraped because your `books` var is empty, because the `'article.product_prod'` selector didn't select anything, because the correct class name is "product_pod".